# Easy way to create string-stream from file-stream

Tags: parsing, stream, common-lisp

I wanted to try `meta-sexp` package.  It's a PEG-like parser library.  Now, it has a method `create-parser-context` which can only take `string` or `string-stream`. (This is where the parsed content comes from.)  However, `open` and friends create `file-stream`.

I've looked into `flexi-streams` library, but couldn't find a straight-forwad way to do it (I could use `octets-to-string` to create a buffer, feeding it to a bidirectional stream etc... but it's a lot of plumbing).  I feel like I'm missing something obvious, and it should be as easy as calling some `flexi-stream` wrapper function.

Comment: AFAIK, PEG parsers need to be able to backtrack, that's why they are easier to implement with strings (apparently esrap-liquid works with streams). Suppose the last element read in your file does not respect your syntax, the code might try to backtrack up to the first character of your file to try another rule. Maybe you can read your input stream into chunks of string (using a dumb parser), then call the peg parser on each string?

Comment: @coredump My understanding is that `meta-sexp` already does backtracking by creating a stream of its own, which it then navigates when it needs to backtrack. (This is the feeling I get from reading the code of `create-parser-context`.) So, hopefully, I don't need to do that too.

Comment: From the same code, the `string-stream` specialization simply reads the whole stream into a new `string` and then calls the `string` specialization.  Perhaps ask the authors of the package to accept any `stream`.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you do need to work with the way of transforming streams from the system meta-sexp readme:

> meta-sexp uses in-memory string vectors, instead of commonly used
>   streams, for efficiently stepping backward and forward through the
>   input.

So meta-sexp works normally with characters and strings, it has implemented some type checkers:

```
CL-USER> (ql:quickload :meta-sexp)
To load "meta-sexp":
  Install 1 Quicklisp release:
    meta-sexp
Downloading http://beta.quicklisp.org/archive/meta-sexp/2010-10-06/meta-sexp-0.1.6.tgz
##########################################################################
; Loading "meta-sexp"
[package meta-sexp]......
(:META-SEXP)

CL-USER> (use-package :meta-sexp)
T

CL-USER> (alpha? #\c)
T
CL-USER> (alpha? #\3)
NIL
CL-USER> (digit? #\3)
3 (2 bits, #x3, #o3, #b11)
```

Then you can use this defining rules to work with strings like the example in the readme:

```
CL-USER> (defrule integer? (&aux (sign 1) d (num 0)) ()
  (:? (:or (:and "-" (:assign sign -1))
           "+"))
  (:+ (:assign d (:type digit?))
      (:assign num (+ (* num 10)
                  (- (char-code d) #.(char-code #\0)))))
  (:return (* sign num)))

CL-USER> (defrule integer? (&aux (sign 1) d (num 0)) ()
  (:? (:or (:and "-" (:assign sign -1))
           "+"))
  (:+ (:assign d (:type digit?))
      (:assign num (+ (* num 10)
                  (- (char-code d) #.(char-code #\0)))))
  (:return (* sign num)))
```

now let's suppose that we have this file

```
parser-test.txt:

patata
123
calimero
34
32
```

we can read as follows ([read-line](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_rd_lin.htm) returns a string):

```
CL-USER> (with-open-file (stream "parser-test.txt")
           (loop for line = (read-line stream nil)
                 while line
                 do (print line)))

"patata" 
"123" 
"calimero" 
"34" 
"32" 
NIL
```

then apply the parser:

```
CL-USER> 
; No values
CL-USER> (with-open-file (stream "parser-test.txt")
           (loop for line = (read-line stream nil)
                 while line
                 do (print (integer? (create-parser-context line)))))

NIL 
123 
NIL 
34 
32 
NIL
```

you can read files, by character, by line ..., take a look at hypersec function [read](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_rd_rd.htm); finally I would recommend this nice post with a big lesson of lisp [Lisp: It's Not About Macros, It's About Read](http://jlongster.com/Lisp--It-s-Not-About-Macros,-It-s-About-Read)

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't update this thread: I actually wrote to the package author. He offered to submit a PR once I have figured out how to do what I wanted. After some time of poking around, I realized that all I actually had to do was to change the type specification from `string-stream` to `stream` to make it work with `file-stream` (It won't take a file-stream with any `:element-type`, but the one which is automatically selected for text files should just work.